# Dependence of the space of holomorphic 1-forms on the complex structure

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am looking for a reference for the following fact:

Assume $M$ is a closed manifold admitting complex structures of Kahler type. Then the space of holomorphic 1-forms on $M$ with respect to a Kahler-type complex structure $J: TM\to TM$ depends continuously on $J$ (as a subspace of the space of all smooth complex-valued 1-forms). The topologies on the spaces of complex structures and 1-forms are the $C^\infty$-ones.